# Sort in a specific order manually

Tags: influxdb

I have following query :

```
SELECT mean("voltage") FROM "cells" WHERE 
("cell" = 'Cell 1' or "cell" = 'Cell 2' OR "cell" = 'Cell 3' OR "cell" = 'Cell 4' OR 
 "cell" = 'Cell 5' OR "cell" = 'Cell 6' OR "cell" = 'Cell 7' OR "cell" = 'Cell 8' OR 
 "cell" = 'Cell 9' OR "cell" = 'Cell 10' OR "cell" = 'Cell 11' OR "cell" = 'Cell 12' OR 
 "cell" = 'Cell 13' OR "cell" = 'Cell 14' OR "cell" = 'Cell 15' OR "cell" = 'Cell 16') 
AND $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($__interval), "cell" fill(linear)
```

My issue is that influx sort as string so I get Cell 1 then Cell 10 where I would like to have Cell 1, Cell 2 ... ... , how can I achieve that ?

Comment: You can try to use WHERE cell IN ("Case 1", "Case 2" ...) or regexp to make your query smaller

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(cell, 6, 12) * 1;
```

Where `SUBSTRING(test, 6, 12)` will remove "Cell " from the beginning and `* 1` will transform the rest to number.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i get `InfluxDB Error: error parsing query: only ORDER BY time supported at this time`